# How to find only the lines that contain two consecutive vowels

Tags: regex, linux

how to find lines that contain consecutive vowels

`$ (filename) | sed '/[a*e*i*o*u]/!d'`

Comment: What do you mean by consecutive vowels here? Lines containing `a`, then `e`, then `i`,  then `o` and then `u` that all may be separated with any number of any chars? Like `grep 'a.*e.*i.*o.*u' file`? Or `grep -E '[aeiou]{2,}' file` to match lines having 2 or more vowels? If you want to use `sed` , it can be something like `sed -n '/[aeiou]\{2,\}/p' file`

Comment: consecutive vowels as in, any lines that contain any consecutive vowels, as for example 'boomerang' or 'Koala', and using only sed command

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, `filename | sed script` attempts to use `filename` as the name of a command, and pipe the output of that command to `sed script`. To simply pipe a file to sed, use `sed script <filename` (or, less generally, for commands which accept a file name argument, `sed script filename`). Compare with how `echo sed` and `cat sed` do different things than just `sed`. `echo` accepts a string argument, `cat` accepts a file name argument, `sed` by its own is a command, but could also be a string (if you pass it to `echo`) or a file name (if you pass it to `cat`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find lines that contain consecutive vowels you should consider using

```
sed -n '/[aeiou]\{2,\}/p' file
```

Here, `[aeiou]\{2,\}` pattern matches 2 or more occurrences (`\{2,\}` is an interval quantifier with the minimum occurrence number set to `2`) and `[aeiou]` is a bracket expression matching any char defined in it.

The `-n` suppresses output, and the `p` command prints specific lines only (that is, `-n` with `p` only outputs the lines that match your pattern).

Or, you may get the same functionality with `grep`:

```
grep '[aeiou]\{2,\}' file
grep -E '[aeiou]{2,}' file
```

Here is an [online demo](https://ideone.com/xreKbl):

```
s="My boomerang
Text here
Koala there"
sed -n '/[aeiou]\{2,\}/p' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
My boomerang
Koala there
```