# How do I count words that contain consecutive vowels using awk?

Tags: awk, count

Fully admit that this is an assignment from school.  I don't know where to start with a resource for a solution since there seems to be limited guides for awk.  I can find guides that address counting in awk, but not how to fulfill the parameters of the assignment.  Can someone point me at some easy to understand beginner's resources or provide some hints on how to start this?  Note that I did take a look at this: [How to find only the lines that contain two consecutive vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52989229/how-to-find-only-the-lines-that-contain-two-consecutive-vowels) & I'd more like to understand how to obtain the answer.

**Assignment Question - Using Awk: Count the number of words that contain consecutive vowels (a, e, i, o, or u), and then display the count. "consecutive vowels" means the word contains two vowels in a row, i.e. "look" and "good" contain consecutive vowels, while "mama" does not. Do not display any lines of the file - the output should be just the count.**

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to add their efforts in their question, so please do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, I don't know where to start with this.  I am looking for a guide that might go over the parameters of the question.  I don't expect someone to solve this for me, as I mention in my post.  Thanks.

Comment: The [Stack Overflow `awk` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info) has a section with links to learning resources.

Comment: Hi James, I was not requesting the solution since I didn't know how to start this.  I was requesting guides to help, not the answer to the question.

Comment: Pretty much definitive manual for GNU awk: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/

Comment: Hi James, Will do.  I've taken a look at the following and they go over basic counts but not counts with parameters: grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html & gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents .  It looks like these 2 guides might be it though.

Comment: @tripleee, Hi, I made dupe of given link but looks like your answer was deleted there, so I removed it, just fyi please. Also that answer given will provide lines but OP needs to print the count, cheers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the noise -- the proposed duplicate was about finding lines, not individual words, so I moved my answer here instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have NOT posted any Input_file, so I have created my own test/sample Input_file as follows, you could take it as a starting point.

Let's say your Input_file is as follows.

```
cat Input_file
look look good good  mama mama mama mama mama mama look look look mama
mama mama mama mama mama good good look mama mama mama mama mama mama good look
```

Then solution is:

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(match($i,/[aeiouAEIOU]{2}/)){ count++ }
  }
  print "Line " FNR " has " count " number of consecutive vowels found."
  count=""
}
' Input_file
```

OR in case your awk is old version then you could use 2 times `[aeiouAEIOU]` to avoid issues(actually `[aeiouAEIOU]{2}` is shortcut of `[aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU]`), also `match` function was used considering that you may have other requirements(eg--> printing index values, mentioned in following explanation, in case you don't need it then use simple condition).

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if(match($i,/[aeiouAEIOU][aeiouAEIOU]/)){ count++ }
  }
  print "Line " FNR " has " count " number of consecutive vowels found."
  count=""
}
' Input_file
```

***Detailed explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '
##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
##Starting a for loop from 1 to till value of NF(number of fields in current line) here.
##In awk by default lines are separated by spaces and NF will have their total number of fields.
    if(match($i,/[aeiouAEIOU]{2}/)){ count++ }
##Checking condiiton if current field is having 2 consecutive vowels then add count variable with 1 here.
##Why I used match here, in case OP needs to have whatever strings are present with its value, OP could make use of
##substr($i,RSTART,RLENGTH) as an index into an array and then could get those values also.
  }
  print "Line " FNR " has " count " number of consecutive vowels found."
##Printing output that current line has how many consecutive vowels into it.
  count=""
##Nullifying count here.
}
' Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Line 1 has 7 number of consecutive vowels found.
Line 2 has 5 number of consecutive vowels found.
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, I'll have to figure out how to post an input file.  In the meantime, how did you arrive at the solution?  Meaning what sites did you consult?  I've taken a look at the following and they go over basic counts but not counts with parameters: https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html & https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents

Comment: @Nekilof, you could learn it from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info I usually prefer this link. Is your Input_file NOT the same as shown one? But this should work for you for any input file too, try it out once?

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check out the awk resources on SO.  :)  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation RavidnerSignh13.  How did you learn awk?

Comment: @Nekilof, your welcome, I learnt from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info and by keep practicing  anyone could learn it, cheers and keep sharing, keep learning on forums :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an annotated solution.

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /[aeiou]{2}/) count++ } END { print count }' file
```

We loop over the number of input fields (`NF`) on each line; if the `i`:th field (`$1`, `$2`, ....) matches the regex, we increment `count`.

So for an input like

```
good food for poor people
is a grand thing
```

the process goes as follows:

- When the script starts, `count` is implicitly initialized to 0. The record separator is newline, so each new line is a new record.
- We then process the first line

  - When `i` is 1, we examine `$1`, which is `good`; it matches `oo`, so `count` gets incremented to 1
  - When `i` is 2, we examine `$2`, which is `food`; it matches `oo`, so `count` gets incremented to 2
  - When `i` is 3, we examine `$3`, which is `for`; it doesn't match
  - etc etc; `poor` and `people` match, too (`oo` and `eo`, respectively) so at the end of the first line, `count` is 4
- We then process the second line

  - When `i` is 1, we examine `$1`, which is `is`; it doesn't match
  - When `i` is 2, we examine `$2`, which is `a`; it doesn't match
  - etc etc; none of the words match, so `count` remains at 4
- When we have read all the input lines, the `END` block executes

  - We print the value of `count`, which is still 4

There are various ways you could make this more involved, or more elegant. If you specify any whitespace as the record separator `RS`, every input word is a separate record, which means `good` is `$1`, then we process the next record; `food` is `$1`, then we process the next record, etc. This simplifies the script itself, but is arguably harder to understand.

```sh
awk -v RS=' ' '/[aeiou]{2}/ { count++ } END { print count }' file
```

Once you understand Awk's processing model, these approaches should be fairly obvious. It should take you no more than an hour or so to learn how Awk operates, with room for experimentation and multiple examples.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation triplee!  How did you start to understand awk?  I find the GNU manual to be very jargon heavy and not new user friendly.  I assume because people use awk for more complicated scripts?

Comment: I think I probably learned Awk from the GNU manual at the time, but that would have been 30+ years ago. I also remember enjoying the O'Reilly book about `sed` and Awk. Most universities have an Awk section in their introduction to Unix and the shell so it should not be hard to find tutorials for any pace of learning. Awk is typically not used for very complex scripts; these days, anything more than a few screenfuls max would tend to be in Python or Ruby etc.